# How to change AVCaptureSession audio volume?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avcapturesession, avcapturemoviefileoutput

I'm capturing video+audio with `AVCaptureSession`. Capture inputs are standard audio and video `AVCaptureDevice`. Capture output is `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput`. How one can change audio volume?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Audio volume could be changed with shared `AVAudioSession` like this:

```
try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setInputGain(0.5)
```